# How to change machinepolicy in powershell? Currently its Allsigned

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0

get-executionpolicy -list

MachinePolicy                                                                                  AllSigned
                                                                                 UserPolicy                                                                                  Undefined
                                                                                    Process                                                                                  Undefined
                                                                                CurrentUser                                                                                  Undefined
                                                                               LocalMachine                                                                               Unrestricted

Answer (score -2):

If you are opening up the machine to all users (perhaps an enterprise TS environment) I WOULD NOT RECOMMEND anything but "ALLSIGNED", however if this is just you putzing around on your local personal machine only, you can set it safely to "UNRESTRICTED" by entering

```
 set-executionpolicy unrestricted
```

THAT BEING SAID HOWEVER, if this is a machine that does not belong to you or is managed by an IT Staff, DO NOT DO this unless you plan on reverting back to "ALLSIGNED" or "Restricted".  This can be done by entering the following command when you are done:

```
 set-execution policy restricted
```

or

```
set-executionpolicy ALLSIGNED
```